# Unable to read Sitecore data written in Redis

Tags: session-state, redis

We are evaluating `REDIS vs SQL Server` for `session state`. During testing, we found that data in REDIS is not readable. It looks like encrypted with assembly information or maybe it is showing an error. This issue is occurring when Key has `_Data` as a suffix. The keys with `_Internal` as suffix are working fine.

[image]

However, When Sessions are stored in the SQL database then it shows clean and readable data.

So, **My question is:** is it expected behavior or there is something wrong? if it is wrong then where should I look to resolve this problem.

Comment: REDIS serializes anything (binary) whereas SQL session state requires things to be serializable (to text). This is why you can read everything stored in SQL. There is nothing wrong otherwise. Avoiding having to serialize (like REDIS does) is actually more efficient/less demanding.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be influenced [by Redis compression setting](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/100/platform-administration-and-architecture/redis-provider-settings-reference.html) on top of binary format:

> You configure the compression attribute to true to enable compression
> of session state data. Compressing session state data reduces the
> amount of data that you need to transfer between the Sitecore instance
> and the Redis database but might cause some additional CPU overhead.